# Finding solutions for expression to be a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Determine all integers such that $$ n^4- n^2 +64$$ is the square of an integer.

The first two lines of the solution given in the textbook is as below:

> Since $n^4-n^2+64>(n^2-1)^2. $ For some non negative integer $k$, 
>   $n^4-n^2+64=(n^2+k)^2$.

I fail to understand what the author tries to say here. Can't this problem be done in another manner?

Comment: $$(n^2+8)^2-(3n)^2=?$$

Comment: $$(n^2+8)^2-(3n)^2=(n^2-3n+8)(n^2+3n+8)$$

If prime $p$ divides both, $p$ will divide $2(n^2+8),6n$

$p$ must divide $6(n^2+8)-n(6n)=48\implies p=2,3$

Clearly, $n^2\pm3n+8$ are even and will be divisible by $3\iff n\equiv1\pmod3$

Comment: How did you convert the expression into $(n^2+8)^2-(3n)^2$

Comment: For large enough $n$, $(n^2-1)^2<n^4-n^2+64<(n^2)^2$ and so $n^4-n^2+64$ cannot be a square. How large is large enough?

Comment: "Given Solution in the textbook is below:"  No it isn't.

Comment: Hmmm, if you have trouble understanding a solution in the textbook, I think a good strategy would be to try to understand it, rather than asking for a different method in the hope that it is easier.  Seeking alternative approaches is great for *increasing* understanding, not for avoiding it.

Comment: @fleablood Ive written that under 'My Doubt'. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: @ErickWong Yes sir, I'll do that. Thank You

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative solution ...
We have $n^4-n^2+64=A^2$. Multiply this by $4$ and complete the square $(2n^2-1)^2+255=4A^2$. So
\begin{eqnarray*}
(2A+2n^2-1)(2A-2n^2+1)= 3 \times 5 \times 17.
\end{eqnarray*}
This gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
2A+2n^2-1 = x \\
2A-2n^2+1= y 
\end{eqnarray*}
There are $4$ possible values for $(x,y)$ ... $(15,17),(17,15),(51,5),(85,3),(255,1)$. These lead to $(A,n^2)$ having the values $(8,0),(8,1),(14,12),(22,21),(64,64)$. The first second and last will give valid answers $\color{red}{n=0}$, $\color{red}{n= \pm 1}$ and $\color{red}{n= \pm 8}$.

Comment: You omitted the negative solutions

Answer (score 6):

If ( with integer $a \geq 1$) $$  (a-1)^2 < w < a^2, $$
then  $w$ is not a square at all. I guess I can add that then
$$ a-1 < \sqrt w < a,  $$
so that $\sqrt w$ is not an integer, it lies strictly between two consecutive integers.

As usual, there are a few cases to check for small $w$

---

You are given $n^4 - n^2 + 64.$ Now, $(n^2)^2 = n^4.$ Also $(n^2 - 1)^2 = n^4 - 2 n^2 + 1.$

For $n \geq 9$ we have $n^2 > 64$ so that $n^4 - n^2 + 64 < n^4.$

For $n \geq 8,$
$$ n^4 - n^2 + 64 - (n^2 - 1)^2 = n^2 - 63 > 0,   $$ so
$$ n^4 - n^2 + 64 > (n^2 - 1)^2.    $$

Alrighty, for $n \geq 9 $ we get
$$  (n^2 - 1)^2 < n^4 - n^2 + 64 < (n^2)^2 $$ so that $n^4 - n^2 + 64$ is NOT a square for $n \geq 9.$

You still need to check $n=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8.$

Comment: In this case between which two squares do we bound the given expression?

Comment: @Viraam finished typing the answer

Comment: ohh ok. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

Following the author's solution, since $n^4-n^2+64>(n^2-1)^2$ any $n^4-n^2+64$ which equals a square can be written as $(n^2+k)^2$ for $k$ a non-negative integer (i.e. $k>-1$ in the $(n^2-1)^2$).  That means $$n^4-n^2+64 = n^4+2kn^2+k^2$$
and $$n^2=\frac{64-k^2}{(2k+1)}.$$  We need to check for $0\leq k\leq 8$ (since $n^2>0$) to see which values are squares, and find only $k=0, 7$ and $8$ work giving us the solutions $n=0, n=\pm1$, and $n=\pm8$.

Comment: Ohh yes thats the way the author did it. One question, why is it that $ n^4-n^2+64>(n^2-1)^2 $ imply that the square must be of the form $(n^2+k)^2$?

Comment: It's just that it's a number that is bigger than $n^2-1$, so whatever number it is, it can be written as $n^2+k$ with $k$ non-negative.  Call the number $m$, then $m-n^2=$ something.  Call that $k$.

Comment: $a^2 = n^4 - n^2 + 64 > (n^2 -1)^2 \implies a \ge n^2 $ .  Let $k = a - n^2$.  Then $a^2 = (n^2 + k)^2 = n^4 - n^2 + 64$.

Comment: Every square $a^2$ is of the form $(n^2 + k)^2$ if you let $k = a - n^2$.  Every number $w$ is of the form $z + k$ for any number $z$ simply by letting $k = w - z$.  You can *always* do that.  In this case we know $k \ge 0$ so that will help.

Comment: @fleablood Ohh OK. thanks A lot. I can understand now.

Comment: @sharding4 Thank you. I get it now.

Comment: @Viraam "[W]hy is it that $n^4-n^2+64>(n^2-1)^2$ imply that the square must be of the form $(n^2+k)^2$?" Since that sentence is what caused you to doubt the author's solution, you should have included it in the body of your original question. By asking the question that was actually on your mind, you would have gotten a useful answer much quicker. At this point you might as well accept this answer and try to ask a question properly next time.

Comment: @DavidK My apologies... I'm new here. Will definitely voice my questions explicitly next time.

Answer (score 3):

$$(n^2-x)^2=n^4-n^2+64=n^4-2xn^2+x^2$$
where $x$ is an integer.Then,
$$n^2=\dfrac{x^2-64 }{2x-1  }\geq 0$$ hence by multiplying both sides by 4
$$4n^2=\dfrac{4x^2-1+1-256 }{2x-1  }=2x+1-\dfrac{255}{2x-1}$$
Since $255=1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 17 $  then the ratio is an integer only if
$$2x-1=\pm 3^a5^b17^c$$ where $a,b,c \in\{0,1\}$

Which will yield:
$$n\in \{0,\pm 1, \pm 8\}$$

Answer (score 3):

Clearly $n^4$ is a square, since $(n^2)^2=n^4$. The next smaller square is $(n^2-1)^2 = n^4-2n^2+1$, which is clearly less than the given expression. So if $n^4-n^2+64$ is a square, it needs to be not less than $n^4$, that is, we need $64\ge n^2 \implies |n|\le8$ (meaning the number of solutions finite and small)

We can see by inspection that $n=\pm8$ provides a solution where $n^4-n^2+64=n^4$, which is square without further checking. Any other solutions will involve a square greater than $n^4$, that is for some $k>0,$ $(n^2+k)^2 = n^4+2kn^2+k^2$. Then we would need $2kn^2+k^2 = -n^2+64$ giving $64=(2k+1)n^2+k^2$. Checking values of $k$ up to $8$, we can find intermediate solutions $(k,n^2)=\{(0,64), (1,21),(2,12), (7,1),(8,0)\}$ of which only $k=\{8,7,0\}$ give integer values for $n$ of $\{0, \pm1,\pm8\}$ (the last of which we already noted).

Answer (score 2):

This is a brute force approach.

The square previous to $\left(n^2\right)^2=n^4$ is $\left(n^2-1\right)^2=n^4-2n^2+1$. Since it is impossible for
$$
n^4-n^2+64\le n^4-2n^2+1\implies n^2\le-63
$$
we are left with
$$
n^4-n^2+64=n^4\implies\color{#C00}{n^2=64}
$$
or
$$
n^4-n^2+64=n^4+2n^2+1\implies n^2=21
$$
or
$$
n^4-n^2+64=n^4+4n^2+4\implies n^2=12
$$
or
$$
n^4-n^2+64=n^4+6n^2+9\implies7n^2=55
$$
or
$$
n^4-n^2+64=n^4+8n^2+16\implies3n^2=16
$$
or
$$
n^4-n^2+64=n^4+10n^2+25\implies11n^2=39
$$
or
$$
n^4-n^2+64=n^4+12n^2+36\implies13n^2=28
$$
or
$$
n^4-n^2+64=n^4+14n^2+49\implies\color{#C00}{n^2=1}
$$
or
$$
n^4-n^2+64=n^4+16n^2+64\implies\color{#C00}{n^2=0}
$$
The next square is $\left(n^2+9\right)^2=n^4+18n^2+81$ and it is impossible for
$$
n^4-n^2+64\ge n^4+18n^2+81\implies19n^2\le-15
$$
Therefore, we have the solution set of
$$
n\in\{0,\pm1,\pm8\}
$$

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking of writing

\begin{align}
   n^4 - n^2 + 64 &= (n^2 + A)^2 \\
   n^4 - n^2 + 64 &= n^4 + 2An^2 + A^2 \\
   2An^2 + n^2 + A^2 &= 64 \\
   n^2(2A+1) &= 64 - A^2 \\
   n^2 &= -\dfrac{A^2 - 64}{2A+1} \\
   n^2 &= -\frac 12A + \frac 14 + \frac{255}{4(2A+1)} \\
   4n^2 &= -2A + 1 + \frac{255}{2A+1}
    & \text{$2A+1$ must be a positive divisor of $255$} \\
\hline
   2A + 1 &\in \{ 1,3,5,15,17,51,85,255  \} \\
   A &\in \{ 0,1,2,7,8,25,42,177  \} \\
   4n^2 &\in \{256, 84, 48, 4, 0, -44, -80, -252 \} \\
   n &\in \pm\{ 8, 1,0  \}
\end{align}

### ALSO

\begin{align}
   n^4 - n^2 + 64 &= A^2 \\
   (n^2-1)^2 + (n^2-1) - (a^2-64) &= 0\\
   n^2-1 &= \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{4A^2-255}}{2}\\
\hline
   4A^2 - 255 &= B^2 \\
   (2A-B)(2A+B) &= 255 \\
   (2A-B, 2A+B) &\in \{(1,255),(3,85),(5,51),(15,17)\} \\
   (A,B) &\in \{(64,127),(22,41),(14,23),(8,1)\} \\
   A &\in \{64,22,14,8\} \\
   n^2-1 &\in \{63, 20, 11, 0, -1\} \\
   n &\in \pm\{8,1,0\}
\end{align}